# First time using node.js X not defined

Tags: node.js

https://github.com/BlaCoiso/scw_parse
I tried to use this repo for decrypting files. I tried to import the SC3D.js file, xml file, and setup but it always says module not found or it's not defined

Comment: can you send your example code?

Comment: What code? I just copied the instrucion code to node.js

Comment: example your .js file, i want see your code, probably you wrong, i setting up scw_parse and work for me without any module not found error

Comment: It's maybe because I'm having an amd processor? I dind't set up a js file. I should have create a js file that does this?

Comment: i dont know, what are you doing? (are you using embedded board like raspberry or odroid or tinker board ... ) and do you have any source code? and  install nodejs from it, i dont know? plz clarify your question, maybe i can help you

Comment: This is a script that can decrypt files from a game. I do this on my pc. I installed node.js. I cloned the repo. The tried to enter this to the node.js. `const SC3D = require("./SC3D");
SC3D.importPath = "/path/to/sc3d/folder";`
Then it prints out it couldn't find module
@taherfattahi